# How to print to console in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I'm using `PostgreSQL` And I want to print a message to the console.

If I use `plpythonu` I use `plpy.notice`
If I use `plpgsql` I use `raise notice`

but how do I print when the function is pure `SQL`?
using `SELECT 'string'` isn't helping me as it print the string in a column and if the message is located in the middle of the code it doesn't show it.
I want something like `raise notice` / `plpy.notice` for `SQL`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION A()
  RETURNS VOID AS
$BODY$ 
                how do i print 'hello world' here?
 $BODY$
  LANGUAGE sql VOLATILE
```

if it was a `plpgsql` I would do:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION A()
  RETURNS VOID AS
$BODY$ 
        Raise Notice 'hello world'
 $BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```

I'm looking for the equivalent in  `LANGUAGE SQL`

Comment: sql does not have this. and should not have.

Comment: You can only do this in PL/pgSQL using `raise notice`

Comment: X-post http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/106144/7788

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In plain SQL there is the [`NOTIFY`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-notify.html) command. That command sends a *payload* to a *channel*. The *channel* and the *payload* can be any string.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION A() RETURNS void AS $BODY$ 
  NOTIFY msg, 'hello world';
$BODY$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

and then:

```
LISTEN msg;
SELECT A();

Asynchronous notification "msg" with payload "hello world" received from server process with PID 3275.

UNLISTEN msg;
```

The message will also have some information on where it originated from. If you really only want the string (the payload), then you would have to parse that out of the full string.

Answer (score 2):

you can only select it in SQL

```
db=# CREATE FUNCTION b() RETURNS text AS                                                                                                                                         
$BODY$                                                                                                                                                                            
select 'Hello there'::text;                                                                                                                                                     
$BODY$                                                                                                                                                                          
 LANGUAGE sql VOLATILE;
CREATE FUNCTION
db=# select b()::text;                                                                                                                                                                
b
-------------
 Hello there
(1 row)
```

Comment: see edit please my question is much more simple and it has nothing to do with python, I just gave it as an example

Comment: How is a function that returns a simple string `VOLATILE`?